How to use a function of functions to be set to specific values?
Constructs, like the following
x[t_]:={x1[t],x2[t]}
x[t_]:=Through[{x1,x2}[t]]
x[t_]:=Comap[{x1,x2},t] (* Experimental in Mathematica *)

can be used, for example, to find individual solutions with DSolve, as in:
DSolve[x'[t] == x[t], x[t], t]

illustrated in this question. In more elaborate constructs and implementations, such as using larger arrays and solving higher order differential equation, it would be helpful to make assignments of specific values to x1[t] and x2[t], for example using x[t0] to set initial conditions as {x1[t0],x2[t0]}, etc.
Question:
Given that for any value of t, e.g. t=0, x[0] becomes {x1[0],x2[0]}, would it be possible and how to set x[0] as {a,b}, so that x1[0]=a and x2[0]=b (or similar)?
Edit
The preliminary part of my question is illustrative examples. This edit is a more detailed illustration of the question itself. Regardless of the construct used, the following dependency is arrived at:
x[t_] := {x1[t], x2[t]}

The  variable x[t] then can be used to specify the t-dependency as
In:    x[t]
Out:        {x1[t], x2[t]}
In:    x[0]
Out:        {x1[0], x2[0]}
In:    x[a]
Out:        {x1[a], x2[a]}

What  construct  x[t_} ?? {x1[t],x2[t]}, relating x[t] with {x1[t],x2[t]}, will allow, for example, the following:
x[0] = {0, 0}

resulting  in
In:    {x1[0], x2[0]}
Out:                 {0, 0}

or, more generally,
x[a] = {b, c}

resulting  in
In:    {x1[a], x2[a]}
Out:                 {b, c}

My interpretation of the relationship, sought as described above, is that x1[t] and x2[t] will also behave as functions, so that for any value of t=a, for which
x[a] = {b, c}

the resulting values of x1[t] and x2[t] will be
In:    x1[a]
Out:        b
In:    x2[a]
Out:        c


Basically, you want x[t] to always expand as {x1[t],x2[t]}, including its appearance in the arguments of functions with attribute HoldAll,HoldFirst etc. Such are the functions Set, SetDelayed etc.
Then, perhaps, the most radical way will be
x[t_] := {x1[t], x2[t]}
x /: f_[a1___, HoldPattern[x[t_]], a2___] := f[a1, {x1[t], x2[t]}, a2];

Examples of its usage:
x'[t] (*=> {x1'[t], x2'[t]}*)
x[t] (*=> {x1[t], x2[t]}*)
x[0] = {1, 2};
{x1[0], x2[0]} (*=> {1,2}*)
x[0] =.;
{x1[0], x2[0]} (*=> {x1[0], x2[0]}*)

or even
x[t_] := {t, t^2};
{x1[t], x2[t]} (*=> {t,t^2}*)
x[t_] =.;
{x1[t], x2[t]} (*=> {x1[t], x2[t]}*)


Thank you. This seems to work fine so far and does what I needed. There is one small peculiarity, which does not cause any problems. I mention it just out of curiosity:  Setting x[t_] := {t, t^2} evaluates to {Null, Null}, while  setting x[t_] = {t, t^2} evaluates to {t, t^2}, as expected and the rest, including derivatives, still seems to work fine.

@ghogoh In fact, this is also what {x1[t_], x2[t_]} := {t, t^2} returns ({Null,Null}). You can use immediate assignment x[t_] = {t, t^2} with all usual precautions (e.g., t should not have value).

Thank you again, Roma Lee. It works, as expected, with my equation solutions.

You can usually turn subscripts into parameters. So, x1 becomes x[1]. Since you can define SubValues, you can use these parameterized expressions as your functions. I'm not entirely sure I understand your situation, but following this strategy would give you, for example, {x[1][0],x[2][0]} instead of {x1[0],x2[0]}. You could come up with a method for initializing a system of equations:
initialize[fn_, xs : {__}, ys : {__}] :=
  MapThread[fn[#1][#2] == #3 &, {Range[Length@xs], xs, ys}] /; Length[xs] == Length[ys];

initialize[x, {t0, t1, t2}, {a, b, c}]
(* {x[1][t0] == a, x[2][t1] == b, x[3][t2] == c} *)

DSolve works just fine with these kinds of expressions.
DSolve[x[1]'[t] == x[1][t], x[1][t], t]
(* {{x[1][t] -> E^t*C[1]}} *)

In fact, you could use initialize to set up the system of equations for DSolve.
DSolve[
  initialize[
    Derivative[1]@*x, 
    {t, t, t}, 
    {x[1][t], x[2][t], x[3][t]}], 
  {x[1][t], x[2][t], x[3][t]}, 
  t]

I've laid out all of the parameterized functions explicitly, but with this strategy you can do it more automatically.
DSolve[
  initialize[
    Derivative[1]@*x, 
    Table[t, 3], 
    Table[x[i][t], {i, 3}]], 
  Table[x[i][t], {i, 3}], 
  t]

Going back to your first examples, you could also do this:
x[n_, var_] := Comap[Array[x, n], var];
x[4, t]
(* {x[1][t], x[2][t], x[3][t], x[4][t]} *)

But I'm really just guessing that this could work. It depends on the details of your actual situation.

Thank you for elaborating your 'initialise' construct. It does work as you demonstrate, however, as much as I understand it, the subscript parameters, allow to compute and evaluate a number of separate variables, i.e. 'x[i][t]' for 'i=1,2,...'.    My question involves the dependency 'x[t_]:={x1[t],x2[t]}'.    For the benefit of clarifying the question, additional illustration is included in the main text.

You can use TagSetDelayed.
For x
ClearAll[x]
x /: Set[x[t_], v_List /; (Length[v] == 2)] := ({x1[t], x2[t]} = v;)
x /: Set[x[t_], s_] := (x1[t] = s; x2[t] = s;)

Then
x[1] = a
{x1[1], x2[1]}


{a, a}


and
x[z] = {i, j}
{x1[z], x2[z]}


{i, j}


Hope this helps.

Thank you. This is a helpful answer. Through some preliminary tests, so far seems to work. There are a few peculiarities, which may be due to my not applying the variable x[t] properly. Here is a description:  Setting, x[t] does not evaluate to {x1[t],x2[t]} and remains of Dimension {1}, although the variables x1[t] and x2[t] respond as intended;  When x[t]={3t+4,t^3}, all three derivatives, x'[t], x1'[t], x2'[t] do not compute, unless x[t_]= or x[t_]:= is used;  Finally, with x[t_]=, x'[t] does not compute and x1'[t], x2'[t] do; with x[t_]:=,  x'[t] computes and x1'[t], x2'[t] do not.
